# Does drinking water right after waking up reduce sleepiness?

Tags: sleep, behavior, lifestyle

[Related](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/16016/26789) but with no answers (at the time of this posting).

Several websites and "health tips" blogs recommend doing this after waking up to reduce sleepiness after waking up. ([references, google search](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=drinking%20water%20right%20after%20waking%20up%20reduce%20sleepiness)).

Is there any proof it works?

Comment: Works for me, but I don't think that'll count as an answer.

Comment: Can you cite some examples?

Comment: @PaulJohnson examples of web pages that say [drinking water right after waking up reduce sleepiness](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=drinking+water+right+after+waking+up+reduce+sleepiness) ??? a ton of.